# Is there a way to get the session information from the Model in PlayFramework?

Tags: java, session, playframework, playframework-2.2, ebean

I create the app by PlayFramework 2.2 with Java.

When saving Model, I want to save the create_user_id / update_user_id as tracking information.
But, unable to retrieve the session information from Model of PlayFramework.

Currently, I pass the User entity from Controller, when save the entities.
because it is awful implementation, When you call Model.save() method to get a login user from the session in the Model side
I want to like us to save implementation.

Please tell me if you know the best practices.

```
public abstract class AbstractTrailModel extends Model {

  public static final int INSERT = 1;
  public static final int UPDATE = 2;
  public static final int DELETE = 3;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @Constraints.Required
  public User createUser;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @Constraints.Required
  public User createUser;

  @Constraints.Required
  public Integer is_delete;


  public void save(User loginUser){

    if(create_time != null){
      setTrailInfo(UPDATE, loginUser);
      super.save();

    }else{
      setTrailInfo(INSERT, loginUser);
      super.save();
    }
  }


  public void setTrailInfo(int code, User loginUser){

    switch(code) {
      case INSERT:
        createUser = loginUser;
      case UPDATE:
      case DELETE:
        updateUser = loginUser;
    }

    if(code == DELETE){
      is_delete = 1;

    }else{
      is_delete = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I known its only possible to get the session from a Controller. 
If you need the User on the model classes, you need the pass the session or the User as an argument everywhere you need.

Comment: I use `play.mvc.Http.Context.current().session()` and `play.mvc.Http.Session.get()`. I was able to get a session information.
I used a different way , but thank you for your comment .